# Error when publishing page with file name "aux"

Tags: publishing

I just came across this most unusual error in Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1. A user created a page named "Auxiliary Aids..." with file name "aux". When we try to publish this page, we get the following error on the publishing queue: **"FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as disk partitions and tape drives. Avoid use of `"\\.\"` in the path."**

[image]

It works fine if you preview the page or if you run it through Template Builder. The cause appears to be the name of the file "aux" when publishing only. If I rename it to anything else, it publishes fine.

It doesn't look like it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx), but is "aux" a reserved keyword in C#? If it is, I'm not familiar with it.

Has anyone come across this before? If you create a blank page with file name "aux", do you get the error? Can you reproduce it in Tridion 2013 too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed windows file system reserved word: http://ionicflux.wordpress.com/2006/09/02/windows-reserved-words/

Just try to create any file with this name

Comment: I remember reading that COM+ was originally going to be called COM3, but that would have been problematic for the same reason. Can't remember where I read it though.